# how to download the image which will be displayed after a cache image on the web page?

Tags: c#, image, caching, download, html-parsing

I want to download an image from a cartoon website. and my app is WinForm,not WebForm.

So let's say that there is an image on the a.html.

Normally, when I click the previous page and am redirected to this page, 
there will be a image :"image is loading",let's say A.jpg, in the same block.

After 5 seconds, the real one,let's say B.jpg, will be displayed.

So what I got is only the caching image rather than the one,B.jpg, which I want.

So..... how should I do it?

Thanks in advance.

ps:  I have posted this qustion for more than 48 hours, and only got a few of answers which don't solve my problem.
I am wondering that why there are only 2 people posted their answers?
Is my question not clear?
If any, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: do you have the content owner's permission to download these images? What you are describing as the 'caching' image could easily be used to prevent exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Chad, Yes it's a totally free cartoon website. Everyone can be there and have a look at their favourate cartoons. I think the purpose of why a caching image is used in there is the onwer wants to give more user friendly performance to us. Because if one clicked on the next page to see the next image, while loading the image,if there is nothing happened, the user may think the website doesn't respond his/her request. So what's your solution to my question? thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Original answer removed since I misunderstood the question entirely.

What you want to do is basically HTML scraping: using the actual html of the page to discover where files are hosted and download them. Because I'm not sure if there are any legal reasons that would prevent you from downloading the image files in this manner, I'm just going to outline an approach to doing this and not provide any working samples or anything. In other words, use this information at your own risk.

Using fiddler2 in Firefox, you should be able to find the domain and full url that one of the images is downloaded from.  Basically just start fiddler2, navigate to the site in firefox, and then look for the biggest file that is downloaded.  That will tell you exactly where the image is coming from.

Next, take a look at the HTML source code for the page you are viewing.  The way this particular site works, it looks like it hides the previous/next downloads in a swf or something, but you can find the urls in the javascript for the page.  Look for a javascript array called picArr.

To download these using a WinForms app, I would use the WebRequest object. Create a request for each image url and save the response to disk.

Comment: Hi rsbarro, thanks to your reply. But I am developing a WinForm App,rather then a WebForm. And I want to download the image rather than how to display the spinner on a web page.So do you have ideas? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Oh, I thought from the original question that you were trying to display images on a web page.  My fault.  So what you're really trying to do is write a WinForms app to automatically harvest images from a cartoon website, right?

Comment: @rsbarro, yes!  so do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you list the website here so I can get a look and see what's happening?

Comment: @rsbarro, sure! http://www.narutom.com/comic/11624.html try to click on next page to see what's the caching image and the cartoon image. I'm looking forward to your solution :)

Comment: @rsbarro,yes after I reviewed it, I found that array as well. I hope I can get it through the HtmlAgilePack, but normally this pack only provides the html nodes for scraping,so I am not sure whether I can get the javascript as well. Anyway thanks a lot :)